# AnalyserNode windowing

Tags: javascript, fft, web-audio-api

The AnalyserNode of WebAudio has a FFT to get the frequency domain data of a sound signal.
I don't understand how the windowing function of the FFT is defined. Is it possible to change the window size or even the window-function (i.e. Hanning or Blackman)?
If the window is not adjustable, what is the window size and which windowing function is used?

Unfortunately I was't able to find that in the docs.

Comment: For more control you can just get time domain data and do it yourself. It also has far less surface area for implementations to differ so you will  get more consistent results as well. I guess the fft api is just for quick demos or prototypes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The spec has been updated with more detail on how the windowing in the AnalyserNode is done:  http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#fft-windowing-and-smoothing-over-time

In summary, the window size is the FFT size, and the window function is fixed to be Blackman window.